# How can I add a custom action in related list rows in lightning?

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience

I wanted to add a custom action 'Block' below the 'Edit' action in each row for the below related list. Its a standard component.

[image]

Are there any configuration available?

Comment: Much needed Lightning functionality but I'm afraid it's not available (yet)